# How powerful of a soldering iron do I need for this job

Tags: soldering, soldering-iron-station

I am working on a 12"x 18" board that has multiple ground plane layers. I am trying to remove a through component that is tied to these ground planes. My 65 watt Hakko iron heats up the entire board but cannot deliver enough power to reflow the (unleaded) solder. I also tried a hot air gun, but that didn't seem to work much better. Obviously, I need something bigger, but how much bigger? I tried a Weller 300W gun, but it was too unwieldy to work with.

Hakko offers some 140W stations and JBC offers at 250W station, but they are both very expensive. I want to make sure to get the right thing if I am going to spend that much money.

Comment: I've heard tell of people heating an entire board by resting it on a clothes iron and then applying heat with a normal soldering iron

Comment: Yes, you need a proper rework station to preheat the board for you. Are you trying to preserve the part or the board?

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes, I am trying to preserve everything. I just want to attach a wire to the point for an alternative power supply source.

Comment: Are you sure the wire is NOT nickel plated per RoHS standards? You cannot easily solder to nickel, you must crimp on a pin that is tin plated and easy to solder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach which often works well for problems of this sort is to have a helper hold a hot air tool (or perhaps less ideally a heat gun) aimed at the work area while you use an iron to do the actual soldering.

Ideally this would be someone who has used the hot air before, or you can demo a bit with just that, show the role distance plays, etc.  And hopefully you can achieve verbal coordination in having them move it away (and that they know how to safely set it down)

Also melt some solder on to the iron tip to improve heat transfer.